# SSL issue (site not secure) on mobile only

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

The website : [asadarslan.me](https://asadarslan.me/)

This is a WordPress based website. On desktop it shows the site is sure but when you open it on mobile it shows the site is not secure. I updated the DNS servers to cloudflare and install the SSL plugins but nothing works.

Please guide how to fix it. Thank you !

I have an SSL issue on my website and I expect any recommendation regarding plugin or any technical support to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I can see your site is secure at mobile as well. Maybe you should clear your cache and cookies for your mobile browser.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

your site is working perfectly fine on my end. Please clear caches in your browser.
Click the wrench icon enter image description here on the browser toolbar. Select Tools.
Select Clear browsing data.
In the dialog that appears, select the checkboxes for the types of information that you want to remove.
Use the menu at the top to select the amount of data that you want to delete.
Select beginning of time to delete everything.
Click Clear browsing data.
Thank you and Happy coding